# Model joints are giving error

Tags: gazebo-1.6

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I designed model in gazebo. I was working fine by this weekend but when I ran it today, it is giving strange error.
I am using Gazebo 1.6.3, ROS-Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
skhan@skhan:~$ gazebo ~/gazebo_ros_plugin/AccMet_Robot.world
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.6.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.6.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Error [parser.cc:719] XML Element[link_name], child of element[parent] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[parent]
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element <parent>
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element <joint>
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element <model>
Error [parser.cc:369] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
         at line 59 in /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-urdfdom-0.2.7-0precise-20130326-0224/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:1686] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no <sdf> element in file[urdf file]
Error [parser.cc:291] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [parser.cc:636] Unable to read file[/home/skhan/gazebo_ros_plugin/models/AccMet_Robot/model.sdf]
Error [parser.cc:710] Error reading element <world>
Error [parser.cc:369] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
         at line 59 in /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-urdfdom-0.2.7-0precise-20130326-0224/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:1686] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no <sdf> element in file[urdf file]
Error [parser.cc:291] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [Server.cc:253] Unable to read sdf file[/home/skhan/gazebo_ros_plugin/AccMet_Robot.world]

Error [ConnectionManager.cc:100] Connection Manager is not running
```

I couldn't resolve it. Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2409/model-joints-are-giving-error/) by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We had recently made some changes the joint sdf syntax, but we decided to revert them since they would be too confusing. Try following the sdf 1.3 joint syntax, for example the [double_pendulum_with_base model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/fd77cfedd0e5dd21ae064bfb2034ed34670c49bb/double_pendulum_with_base/model-1_3.sdf?at=default#cl-186).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-18**:
I m following that syntex. But strange thing was that before weekend it was working but when I updated my Gazebo this week its no more working. When i comment out joint part then links are working fine keeping model static.

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-18**:
Problem is solved I realized after updating my sdf file using gzsdf it changes from

```
   <child>finger2</child>
```

to

<link_name>finger2</link_name>

so i converted it back. Now things are better =)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Problem is solved I realized after updating my sdf file using gzsdf it somehow changes from

```
<parent>base</parent>
<child>shoulder</child>
```

to

```
<parent>
  <link_name>base</link_name>
</parent>
<child>
  <link_name>shoulder</link_name>
</child>
```

so i converted it back. Now things are better =)

---

Originally posted by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) with karma: 131 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-20**:
I had the same problem now after an udpate. I had to fix it this way. Thanks

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-23**:
You are Welcome